# How do I require a file in meteor 1.3?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, reactjs

I'm trying to use [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/) in a meteor 1.3 and react project.

Everything is working fine except that I don't have access to any of the css in the package. The readme says I need to require the css file from the package.

If I wasn't using meteor I could start the file with:

```
var React = require('react');
var DatePicker = require('react-datepicker');
var moment = require('moment');

require('react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css');
```

Since this is meteor 1.3 I started it with

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
```

I don't know how to require the css file. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: `import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I found was using relative paths inside an .scss file.

```
@import "./../../../../node_modules/react-date-picker/base.css";
@import "./../../../../node_modules/react-date-picker/theme/hackerone.css";
```

Ugly as f***, I know, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

`import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';` worked! 
Thanks @apendua